# Google Maps Geocode not working (no markers)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a webpage to find latitude, longitude, and get a marker for that position. I use Google Maps.

My webpage get 2 addresses from user input, address 1 and address 2, and calls `codeAddress()`

```html
<div id="panel">
  <input id="address1" type="textbox" value="">
  <input id="address2" type="textbox" value="">
  <input type="button" value="find!" onclick="codeAddress()">
</div>
```

This is my JavaScript code:

```javascript
var map;
var address1 = document.getElementById('address1').value;
var address2 = document.getElementById('address2').value;

function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-7.275920, 112.791871);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

function codeAddress() {
    var gc = google.maps.Geocoder();
    gc.geocode({
        'address': address1
    }, function (res1, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            gc.geocode({
                'address': address2
            }, function (res2, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: res1[0].geometry.location,
                        map: map
                    });
                    new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: res2[0].geometry.location,
                        map: map
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

When I click the button `find`, I didn’t get the markers. Can any body help me?

Answer (score 1):

Modify the `codeAddress` function like this:

```
function codeAddress() {
    var gc = new google.maps.Geocoder(); // notice new keyword
    initialize(); // Calling initialize. If you skip it, maps aren't loading
    gc.geocode({
        'address': address1
    }, function(res1, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            gc.geocode({
                'address': address2
            }, function(res2, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: res1[0].geometry.location,
                        map: map
                    });
                    new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: res2[0].geometry.location,
                        map: map
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Make sure both of the inputs have some value to test it.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/213/

Comment: You can just point out he's missing `initialize()` and the `new` keyword. I don't think there's a need for the entire code.

Comment: I think we need to provide some code if we have to include jsfiddle links.

Comment: ur code is right. . but when i set the value from input text from web , i didn't get the markers

Comment: I believe that's because initially you have stored the values of inputs in variables and assuming that the initial values of inputs are none. So your variables holds none value and same is passed to the map. If you try moving the variable initialisation code for address1 and address2 inside codeAddress, then it will work, because your values are dynamic. If they were constant then you could have followed this approach

Comment: @KK Yes, but there is not point in writing the code twice. Unless you simply want the OP to copy paste and not learn anything from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

- update the address variables from the form when the function runs

  ```
  function codeAddress() {
    var address1 = document.getElementById('address1').value;
    var address2 = document.getElementById('address2').value;
  ```
- check for status != OK

  ```
  } else alert("Geocode failed of " + address1 + ", status=" + status);
  ```
- use "new" before the google maps Geocoder constructor

  ```
  var gc = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  ```
- remove existing markers before displaying new ones so the markers don't accumulate on the map

  ```
  if (marker1 && marker1.setMap) marker1.setMap(null);
  ```

complete code:

```
    var map = null;
    var marker1 = null;
    var marker2 = null;
    var gc = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    function initialize() {
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-7.275920, 112.791871);
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
      codeAddress();
    }

    function codeAddress() {
      var address1 = document.getElementById('address1').value;
      var address2 = document.getElementById('address2').value;
      gc.geocode({
        'address': address1
      }, function (res1, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            gc.geocode({
                'address': address2
            }, function (res2, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    if (marker1 && marker1.setMap) marker1.setMap(null);
                    marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: res1[0].geometry.location,
                        map: map
                    });
                    if (marker2 && marker2.setMap) marker2.setMap(null);
                    marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: res2[0].geometry.location,
                        map: map
                    });
                } else alert("Geocode failed of " + address2 + ", status=" + status);
            });
        } else alert("Geocode failed of " + address1 + ", status=" + status);
      });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YuGt3/1/)